# write driver for opensc unknown card

Tags: driver, javacard, opensc

I'm trying to use opensc for my project, but unfortunately it does not support my java card. I though it will, because it has two drivers called "javacard" and "default" but none is compatible with mine (Kona26 card).

Does anybody know how I can write my own driver or any trick by which I can use opensc with my cards?

thanks in advance,

Comment: KONA cards seem to provide identity solutions for Thailand. So I presume you want to use your card for signature generation using OpenSC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read [this article](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/Adding-a-new-card-driver) from Github, which shows how to add a new card driver to make OpenSC work with your cards. Hope it helps!